# Azure DevOps: how to set a variable to a value based on the stage

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops

In my Xamarin.Forms application (that supports iOS, Android, UWP), I have a config.json file that defines some variables, e.g.

{
      "HideExperimentalFeature": false
   }

Is it possible in the AzureDevops pipeline to inject a value for a variable based on stage, e.g. QA or Production? E.g. for QA it can be set to false, and for Production true. Is it possible to do it using user interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *replace tokens* in files:

1. swap it in your json file to a token, ie. `{ "HideExperimentalFeature": #{HideExperimentalFeature}# }`
2. In your release pipeline you set these variables:

   - HideExperimentalFeature: *true* for Prod stage
   - HideExperimentalFeature: *false* for QA stage
3. Add a *Replace Tokens* task to your pipeline:

   - Target files: *path/to/config.json*
   - Missing variables / action: *fail*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I replace the bool value with a token, I will not be able to run it in Visual Studio, right?

Comment: @DavidShochet I was hoping that you can just have the config.json file, and also a config.Development.json that will override that single value (without the _token_) similarly asp.net core. Seems like that's not the case with Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Replace Tokens` [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens&targetId=1e4dea8d-0e41-45a5-ad9f-c0225096a67e).

in `config.json` file just add key markers, and tell the extension which files should be scanned for replacement.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "#{connection_string}#"
  },
  { "HideExperimentalFeature": #{HideExperimentalFeature}# }
}
```

`connection_string` will be replaced with proper value based on stage. Also, you can use `Release` stage which means "use it everywhere". What is more, you can you `Release + stage_x`, and then `Release` will be used as default, and `stage_x` will override it on its stage.

Consider `Missing variable behavior` set as `Fail pipeline` due to the fact, `Log Warn` is usually not noticed in the woods of logs.

Also, Azure DevOps variables nature allows you using `Settable as release time` option next to the variable definition. Then, you can pass the value

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to mark another one, as it appeared one minute earlier, so I could just vote your +. But I really appreciate it.